# React: Use environment variables

Tags: reactjs

How can I use environment variables defined in `.bash_profile` in a React application? I have two React apps in production (they're the same project, so they have the same code), but they need to request to different API hosts, and I figured env variables could do the trick.

Comment: have you tried _anything_?

Comment: Do you use some kind of module bundler ? webpack ? browserify ?

Comment: You don't state what you are using, but usually this is done in the server side as I doubt JS can read any environment variables. In node you could do `process.env.API_HOST`

Comment: @topheman We're using webpack

Comment: @eblin, I don't mean for the JS running in the client to be able to read env variables. What we want is to insert values from those variables on compilation time.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `webpack.DefinePlugin`. Say you exported `FOO` and `BAR` in your `.bash_profile`, then your webpackconfig should look like:

```
const config = {
  entry: 'somescript',
  // ...
  module: {
    // ...
  },
  // ...
  plugins: [
    // ... your plugins
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env':{
        'FOO': process.env.FOO,
        'BAR': process.env.BAR
      }
    })
  ],
  // ...
}
```

You will be able to access those in your js at compile time via `process.env.FOO` & `process.env.BAR`

Resource: https://github.com/topheman/webpack-babel-starter

Comment: As you said it only will work at build time. @sauronnikko said that he has two projects with the same code. According to your solution, he will have two different applications i.e with different code.

Comment: just read a comment to the ticket and it seems it what they need. Sorry man.

Comment: @MikhailChibel Yes, sorry the question wasn't clear. I wanted the variables to work at build time

Comment: I also had to stringify the var like so: `JSON.stringify(process.env.FOO)` otherwise it will not work. Btw, I come from the future.

Answer (score -2):

Store the environment variables in the `index.html`!

if you treat the `index.html` like a deployment manifest that contains environment-specific values, you can use the same versioned assets (js, css) in every environment!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://assets.myapp.com/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="https://assets.myapp.com/manifest.json">
    <title>React App</title>
    <script>
      env = {
        // Add your environment variables here
        api: "https://staging-api.myapp.com"
      };
    </script>
    <link href="https://assets.myapp.com/static/css/main.6bd13355.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://assets.myapp.com/static/js/1.a700ff87.chunk.js"></script>
    <script src="https://assets.myapp.com/static/js/main.3ec5cdc6.chunk.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In your code reference the values directly: `myApi = window.env.api;`

Read more documentation for this methodology at https://immutablewebapps.org

Comment: I am looking for feedback on how I can improve this answer or if I should remove it -- thank you!